# Wi-Fi 6: WPA3-Personal authentication on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: networking, wireless, network-manager, wpa3

I use Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and I'm having the problem that the classical network manager has as maximum security authentication WPA & WPA2 Personal.

The problem is that I want to have access to networks with WPA3-Personal authentication and I'm not able to connect to them in this moment.

Can someone to explain me how to fix this problem? Maybe the installation of a packet, library or even reinstalling Ubuntu 18.04 LTS will fix the problem? I don't know.

Comment: Please see: https://www.ubuntufree.com/networkmanager-1-16-released-with-wpa3-personal-and-wireguard-vpn-support-more/ What is the version of NM that you have installed? `sudo dpkg -s network-manager | grep Version`  Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Hi!, this was the output of the command: Version: 1.10.6-2ubuntu1.4

Answer (score 2):

Please see these bug reports: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/1844422 and also: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager-applet/+bug/1848339 WPA3-SAE capability is included in Network Manager version 1.20-2 and associated packages.

I know of no way, however, to reliably install the later versions of Network Manager, wpa-supplicant, et al on to Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

I recommend that you install a fully updated version (Ubuntu, lubuntu, kubuntu, etc.) of 19.10. I suspect that WPA3-SAE will then work properly.

Comment: Thanks for the response but it seems this does not solve the problem at a 100%. I was wondering if you could tell me the commands and the steps I should use on the terminal to install what the bug reports suggest?. I will try them out and tell you the output.

Comment: I haven't any idea. The commits in the bug reports are to change the source code for Network Manager; thereafter, it is recompiled and a later version number added, for example. network-manager-1.20.4-2ubuntu2.1 becomes 2.2 or some such. This is the packaged in a deb package that, depending on your kernel version and gcc version, installs on your system. The commits are not, as far as I can tell, intended nor usable in NM 1.10-xx. All of this is very far beyond the scope of this answer. Did you try the live session of Ubuntu 19.10 daily build to see if it works?

Comment: I understand; the thing is 18.04 is a long term supported and 19.10 it not so it may come with bugs that will be fix only until the LTS version. I haven't tried the live version of 19.10. I will try it out and comment the outcome.

Comment: Well it didn't go well. I booted 19.10 and has the same authentication (Wi-Fi Security) methods as 18.04 LTS. Does anyone know how to fix this?.

Comment: One of the bug reports suggests that it is working using nmtui. Please try.

Comment: Hi, I just tried nmtui through the terminal and it didn't work. It seems the packet is not configured to detect WPA3-SAE yet or there is a configuration that has to be made manually. I will investigate but no one has written about this subject yet and that's why is so interesting.

Comment: Hi, the problem was fixed when I turned off secure boot and also upgraded my system to 20.04 LTS; no connection problem in fact the Wi-Fi is now flying.