# How to use WPA3 and protected managment frames with Ubuntu 20.10?

Tags: security, iwlwifi, wpa3

I have an Intel AX-210 in a Dell Latitude-7480 notebook running Ubuntu 20.10. I want to connect using Wi-Fi 6E, using WPA3 and protected management frames (both required in 6 GHz).
driver is iwlfifi /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0-59.ucode

Ubuntu sees the SSID, but it will not connect. It displays a pop up message "Activation of network connection failed" multiple times.

I'm looking at the article on [WPA3 with 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1290589/how-to-use-wpa3-with-ubuntu-20-04.).

The accepted answer provides this procedure:

```
nmcli conn show
NAME                                UUID                                  TYPE      DEVICE 
mywifi                              xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxx  wifi      wlp1s0 
...other connections here...
```

> We then use the nmcli interactive editor to fix the key-mgmt in use as
> follows:
>
> nmcli conn edit mywifi

My system shows this:

```
$ nmcli conn show
NAME                UUID                                  TYPE      DEVICE    
WiFi-6E-Test 2      b84117dd-fa12-4dba-b273-61f5fe3c9af1  wifi      wlp2s0    
Wired connection 1  0f8fd576-7856-3fc4-b8fe-7e524e3fe47d  ethernet  enp0s31f6 
WiFi-6E-Test        4019de60-86ee-48e1-bb3c-43dfef87f79e  wifi      --        
WiFi-6E-Test 1      bd490295-3372-4c4b-b906-7aa9c14e2490  wifi      --
```

The first line "WiFi-6E-Test 2" is red while the system is attempting to connect.
The wired connection is green, and the other Wi-Fi connections are white.
The actual SSID is Wi-Fi-6E-Test.  I'm not sure why the 1 and 2 are added, but it may be different security types that have been tried (none, OWE, and WPA3).

I tried the process, but it seems the key management was already sae:

```
$ nmcli conn edit "WiFi-6E-Test 2" 

===| nmcli interactive connection editor |===

Editing existing '802-11-wireless' connection: 'WiFi-6E-Test 2'

Type 'help' or '?' for available commands.
Type 'print' to show all the connection properties.
Type 'describe [<setting>.<prop>]' for detailed property description.

You may edit the following settings: connection, 802-11-wireless (wifi), 802-11-wireless-security (wifi-sec), 802-1x, ethtool, match, ipv4, ipv6, tc, proxy
nmcli> print wifi-sec.key-mgmt
802-11-wireless-security.key-mgmt: sae
nmcli> describe wifi-sec.key-mgmt

=== [key-mgmt] ===
[NM property description]
Key management used for the connection.  One of "none" (WEP), "ieee8021x" (Dynamic WEP), "wpa-psk" (infrastructure WPA-PSK), "sae" (SAE), "owe" (Opportunistic Wireless Encryption) or "wpa-eap" (WPA-Enterprise).  This property must be set for any Wi-Fi connection that uses security.

nmcli> set wifi-sec.key-mgmt sae
nmcli> verify
Verify connection: OK
nmcli> save persistent
Connection 'WiFi-6E-Test 2' (b84117dd-fa12-4dba-b273-61f5fe3c9af1) successfully updated.
nmcli>
```

So far this has not worked.
Are there other settings needed to enable support of protected management frames?

I also tried changing the AP to Opportunistic Wireless Encryption instead of WPA3. I repeated the nmcli steps but used owe instead of sae.
This does not work either.  Using OWE the repeating messages "Activation of network connection failed"  do not appear. It just silently fails.

In both cases, the SSID is visible in the Select Network dialog, but it never associates.

Here is the result of  sudo tail -f /var/log/syslog during a failure to connect with the AP using WPA3:

```
Mar 14 17:26:31 ****-Latitude-7480 NetworkManager[542]: <info>  [1615760791.0592] device (wlp2s0): Activation: starting connection 'six-e-test' (4b4e0bc9-436c-4194-8901-46c9247d0fa4)
Mar 14 17:26:31 ****-Latitude-7480 NetworkManager[542]: <info>  [1615760791.0593] audit: op="connection-add-activate" uuid="4b4e0bc9-436c-4194-8901-46c9247d0fa4" name="six-e-test" pid=1096 uid=1000 result="success"
Mar 14 17:26:31 ****-Latitude-7480 NetworkManager[542]: <info>  [1615760791.0617] device (wlp2s0): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Mar 14 17:26:31 ****-Latitude-7480 NetworkManager[542]: <info>  [1615760791.0622] device (wlp2s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Mar 14 17:26:31 ****-Latitude-7480 NetworkManager[542]: <info>  [1615760791.0628] device (wlp2s0): Activation: (wifi) access point 'six-e-test' has security, but secrets are required.
Mar 14 17:26:31 ****-Latitude-7480 NetworkManager[542]: <info>  [1615760791.0630] device (wlp2s0): state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Mar 14 17:26:40 ****-Latitude-7480 NetworkManager[542]: <info>  [1615760800.1146] device (wlp2s0): state change: need-auth -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Mar 14 17:26:40 ****-Latitude-7480 NetworkManager[542]: <info>  [1615760800.1150] device (wlp2s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Mar 14 17:26:40 ****-Latitude-7480 NetworkManager[542]: <info>  [1615760800.1153] device (wlp2s0): Activation: (wifi) connection 'six-e-test' has security, and secrets exist.  No new secrets needed.
Mar 14 17:26:40 ****-Latitude-7480 NetworkManager[542]: <info>  [1615760800.1153] Config: added 'ssid' value 'six-e-test'
Mar 14 17:26:40 ****-Latitude-7480 NetworkManager[542]: <info>  [1615760800.1153] Config: added 'scan_ssid' value '1'
Mar 14 17:26:40 ****-Latitude-7480 NetworkManager[542]: <info>  [1615760800.1153] Config: added 'bgscan' value 'simple:30:-70:86400'
Mar 14 17:26:40 ****-Latitude-7480 NetworkManager[542]: <info>  [1615760800.1154] Config: added 'key_mgmt' value 'SAE FT-SAE'
Mar 14 17:26:40 ****-Latitude-7480 NetworkManager[542]: <info>  [1615760800.1154] Config: added 'auth_alg' value 'OPEN'
Mar 14 17:26:40 ****-Latitude-7480 NetworkManager[542]: <info>  [1615760800.1154] Config: added 'psk' value '<hidden>'
Mar 14 17:26:40 ****-Latitude-7480 NetworkManager[542]: <info>  [1615760800.1286] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Mar 14 17:26:40 ****-Latitude-7480 NetworkManager[542]: <info>  [1615760800.1287] device (p2p-dev-wlp2s0): supplicant management interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Mar 14 17:26:49 ****-Latitude-7480 systemd-resolved[503]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
Mar 14 17:26:50 ****-Latitude-7480 systemd-resolved[503]: message repeated 3 times: [ Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.]
Mar 14 17:27:04 ****-Latitude-7480 NetworkManager[542]: <warn>  [1615760824.8831] device (wlp2s0): Activation: (wifi) association took too long, failing activation
Mar 14 17:27:04 ****-Latitude-7480 NetworkManager[542]: <info>  [1615760824.8833] device (wlp2s0): state change: config -> failed (reason 'ssid-not-found', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Mar 14 17:27:04 ****-Latitude-7480 NetworkManager[542]: <warn>  [1615760824.8875] device (wlp2s0): Activation: failed for connection 'six-e-test'
Mar 14 17:27:04 ****-Latitude-7480 NetworkManager[542]: <info>  [1615760824.8880] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> disconnected
Mar 14 17:27:04 ****-Latitude-7480 NetworkManager[542]: <info>  [1615760824.8880] device (p2p-dev-wlp2s0): supplicant management interface state: scanning -> disconnected
Mar 14 17:27:04 ****-Latitude-7480 NetworkManager[542]: <info>  [1615760824.8884] device (wlp2s0): state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Mar 14 17:27:04 ****-Latitude-7480 wpa_supplicant[584]: wlp2s0: Reject scan trigger since one is already pending
Mar 14 17:27:05 ****-Latitude-7480 wpa_supplicant[584]: wlp2s0: Reject scan trigger since one is already pending
Mar 14 17:27:05 ****-Latitude-7480 NetworkManager[542]: <info>  [1615760825.9012] policy: auto-activating connection 'six-e-test' (4b4e0bc9-436c-4194-8901-46c9247d0fa4)
Mar 14 17:27:05 ****-Latitude-7480 NetworkManager[542]: <info>  [1615760825.9030] device (wlp2s0): Activation: starting connection 'six-e-test' (4b4e0bc9-436c-4194-8901-46c9247d0fa4)
Mar 14 17:27:05 ****-Latitude-7480 NetworkManager[542]: <info>  [1615760825.9035] device (wlp2s0): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Mar 14 17:27:05 ****-Latitude-7480 NetworkManager[542]: <info>  [1615760825.9055] device (wlp2s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Mar 14 17:27:05 ****-Latitude-7480 NetworkManager[542]: <info>  [1615760825.9062] device (wlp2s0): Activation: (wifi) access point 'six-e-test' has security, but secrets are required.
Mar 14 17:27:05 ****-Latitude-7480 NetworkManager[542]: <info>  [1615760825.9062] device (wlp2s0): state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Mar 14 17:27:05 ****-Latitude-7480 NetworkManager[542]: <info>  [1615760825.9086] device (wlp2s0): state change: need-auth -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Mar 14 17:27:05 ****-Latitude-7480 NetworkManager[542]: <info>  [1615760825.9091] device (wlp2s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Mar 14 17:27:05 ****-Latitude-7480 NetworkManager[542]: <info>  [1615760825.9094] device (wlp2s0): Activation: (wifi) connection 'six-e-test' has security, and secrets exist.  No new secrets needed.
Mar 14 17:27:05 ****-Latitude-7480 NetworkManager[542]: <info>  [1615760825.9094] Config: added 'ssid' value 'six-e-test'
Mar 14 17:27:05 ****-Latitude-7480 NetworkManager[542]: <info>  [1615760825.9094] Config: added 'scan_ssid' value '1'
Mar 14 17:27:05 ****-Latitude-7480 NetworkManager[542]: <info>  [1615760825.9095] Config: added 'bgscan' value 'simple:30:-70:86400'
Mar 14 17:27:05 ****-Latitude-7480 NetworkManager[542]: <info>  [1615760825.9095] Config: added 'key_mgmt' value 'SAE FT-SAE'
Mar 14 17:27:05 ****-Latitude-7480 NetworkManager[542]: <info>  [1615760825.9095] Config: added 'auth_alg' value 'OPEN'
Mar 14 17:27:05 ****-Latitude-7480 NetworkManager[542]: <info>  [1615760825.9095] Config: added 'psk' value '<hidden>'
Mar 14 17:27:05 ****-Latitude-7480 wpa_supplicant[584]: wlp2s0: Reject scan trigger since one is already pending
Mar 14 17:27:05 ****-Latitude-7480 wpa_supplicant[584]: wlp2s0: Failed to initiate AP scan
Mar 14 17:27:06 ****-Latitude-7480 wpa_supplicant[584]: wlp2s0: Reject scan trigger since one is already pending
Mar 14 17:27:06 ****-Latitude-7480 wpa_supplicant[584]: wlp2s0: Failed to initiate AP scan
Mar 14 17:27:07 ****-Latitude-7480 wpa_supplicant[584]: wlp2s0: Reject scan trigger since one is already pending
Mar 14 17:27:07 ****-Latitude-7480 wpa_supplicant[584]: wlp2s0: Failed to initiate AP scan
Mar 14 17:27:08 ****-Latitude-7480 wpa_supplicant[584]: wlp2s0: Reject scan trigger since one is already pending
Mar 14 17:27:08 ****-Latitude-7480 wpa_supplicant[584]: wlp2s0: Failed to initiate AP scan
Mar 14 17:27:09 ****-Latitude-7480 wpa_supplicant[584]: wlp2s0: Reject scan trigger since one is already pending
Mar 14 17:27:09 ****-Latitude-7480 wpa_supplicant[584]: wlp2s0: Failed to initiate AP scan
Mar 14 17:27:10 ****-Latitude-7480 NetworkManager[542]: <info>  [1615760830.9318] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Mar 14 17:27:10 ****-Latitude-7480 NetworkManager[542]: <info>  [1615760830.9319] device (p2p-dev-wlp2s0): supplicant management interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Mar 14 17:27:15 ****-Latitude-7480 systemd-resolved[503]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
Mar 14 17:27:15 ****-Latitude-7480 systemd-resolved[503]: message repeated 3 times: [ Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.]
Mar 14 17:27:30 ****-Latitude-7480 NetworkManager[542]: <warn>  [1615760850.8830] device (wlp2s0): Activation: (wifi) association took too long, failing activation
Mar 14 17:27:30 ****-Latitude-7480 NetworkManager[542]: <info>  [1615760850.8831] device (wlp2s0): state change: config -> failed (reason 'ssid-not-found', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Mar 14 17:27:30 ****-Latitude-7480 NetworkManager[542]: <warn>  [1615760850.8870] device (wlp2s0): Activation: failed for connection 'six-e-test'
Mar 14 17:27:30 ****-Latitude-7480 NetworkManager[542]: <info>  [1615760850.8873] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> disconnected
Mar 14 17:27:30 ****-Latitude-7480 NetworkManager[542]: <info>  [1615760850.8873] device (p2p-dev-wlp2s0): supplicant management interface state: scanning -> disconnected
Mar 14 17:27:30 ****-Latitude-7480 NetworkManager[542]: <info>  [1615760850.8881] device (wlp2s0): state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Mar 14 17:27:40 ****-Latitude-7480 systemd-resolved[503]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
Mar 14 17:27:41 ****-Latitude-7480 systemd-resolved[503]: message repeated 3 times: [ Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.]
Mar 14 17:28:02 ****-Latitude-7480 NetworkManager[542]: <info>  [1615760882.6225] policy: auto-activating connection 'six-e-test' (4b4e0bc9-436c-4194-8901-46c9247d0fa4)
Mar 14 17:28:02 ****-Latitude-7480 NetworkManager[542]: <info>  [1615760882.6229] device (wlp2s0): Activation: starting connection 'six-e-test' (4b4e0bc9-436c-4194-8901-46c9247d0fa4)
Mar 14 17:28:02 ****-Latitude-7480 NetworkManager[542]: <info>  [1615760882.6230] device (wlp2s0): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Mar 14 17:28:02 ****-Latitude-7480 NetworkManager[542]: <info>  [1615760882.6234] device (wlp2s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Mar 14 17:28:02 ****-Latitude-7480 NetworkManager[542]: <info>  [1615760882.6237] device (wlp2s0): Activation: (wifi) access point 'six-e-test' has security, but secrets are required.
Mar 14 17:28:02 ****-Latitude-7480 NetworkManager[542]: <info>  [1615760882.6237] device (wlp2s0): state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Mar 14 17:28:02 ****-Latitude-7480 NetworkManager[542]: <info>  [1615760882.6271] device (wlp2s0): state change: need-auth -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Mar 14 17:28:02 ****-Latitude-7480 NetworkManager[542]: <info>  [1615760882.6275] device (wlp2s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Mar 14 17:28:02 ****-Latitude-7480 NetworkManager[542]: <info>  [1615760882.6277] device (wlp2s0): Activation: (wifi) connection 'six-e-test' has security, and secrets exist.  No new secrets needed.
Mar 14 17:28:02 ****-Latitude-7480 NetworkManager[542]: <info>  [1615760882.6278] Config: added 'ssid' value 'six-e-test'
Mar 14 17:28:02 ****-Latitude-7480 NetworkManager[542]: <info>  [1615760882.6278] Config: added 'scan_ssid' value '1'
Mar 14 17:28:02 ****-Latitude-7480 NetworkManager[542]: <info>  [1615760882.6278] Config: added 'bgscan' value 'simple:30:-70:86400'
Mar 14 17:28:02 ****-Latitude-7480 NetworkManager[542]: <info>  [1615760882.6278] Config: added 'key_mgmt' value 'SAE FT-SAE'
Mar 14 17:28:02 ****-Latitude-7480 NetworkManager[542]: <info>  [1615760882.6278] Config: added 'auth_alg' value 'OPEN'
Mar 14 17:28:02 ****-Latitude-7480 NetworkManager[542]: <info>  [1615760882.6278] Config: added 'psk' value '<hidden>'
Mar 14 17:28:02 ****-Latitude-7480 NetworkManager[542]: <info>  [1615760882.6394] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Mar 14 17:28:02 ****-Latitude-7480 NetworkManager[542]: <info>  [1615760882.6394] device (p2p-dev-wlp2s0): supplicant management interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Mar 14 17:28:12 ****-Latitude-7480 systemd-resolved[503]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
^C
```

Here is the syslog when the AP is changed to Enhanced Open (Opportunistic Wireless Encryption).

```
****@****-Latitude-7480:~$ sudo tail -f /var/log/syslog
Mar 14 17:50:58 ****-Latitude-7480 NetworkManager[542]: <info>  [1615762258.5147] audit: op="connection-add-activate" pid=4029 uid=1000 result="fail" reason="Failed to determine AP security information"
Mar 14 17:50:58 ****-Latitude-7480 gnome-control-c[4029]: Failed to add and activate connection '0': Failed to determine AP security information
Mar 14 17:50:59 ****-Latitude-7480 NetworkManager[542]: <info>  [1615762259.7447] audit: op="connection-add-activate" pid=4029 uid=1000 result="fail" reason="Failed to determine AP security information"
Mar 14 17:50:59 ****-Latitude-7480 gnome-control-c[4029]: Failed to add and activate connection '0': Failed to determine AP security information
Mar 14 17:51:01 ****-Latitude-7480 NetworkManager[542]: <info>  [1615762261.3282] audit: op="connection-add-activate" pid=4029 uid=1000 result="fail" reason="Failed to determine AP security information"
Mar 14 17:51:01 ****-Latitude-7480 gnome-control-c[4029]: Failed to add and activate connection '0': Failed to determine AP security information
Mar 14 17:51:02 ****-Latitude-7480 NetworkManager[542]: <info>  [1615762262.6328] audit: op="connection-add-activate" pid=4029 uid=1000 result="fail" reason="Failed to determine AP security information"
Mar 14 17:51:02 ****-Latitude-7480 gnome-control-c[4029]: Failed to add and activate connection '0': Failed to determine AP security information
Mar 14 17:51:04 ****-Latitude-7480 systemd-resolved[503]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
Mar 14 17:51:05 ****-Latitude-7480 systemd-resolved[503]: message repeated 3 times: [ Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.]
Mar 14 17:51:12 ****-Latitude-7480 wpa_supplicant[584]: wlp2s0: Reject scan trigger since one is already pending
Mar 14 17:52:32 ****-Latitude-7480 wpa_supplicant[584]: message repeated 3 times: [ wlp2s0: Reject scan trigger since one is already pending]
```