# How to use wpa_supplicant for Wi-Fi configuration in Ubuntu 20.10?

Tags: networking, network-manager, iwlwifi, wpa-supplicant

I have a system with Ubuntu 20.10, kernel 5.11 with the Intel AX-210 Wi-Fi NIC with iwlwifi-ty-59.601f3a66.0.tgz driver.

I've found that Network Manager currently does not support [WPA3](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1323557/how-to-use-wpa3-and-protected-managment-frames-with-ubuntu-20-10) and [OWE (Enhanced Open)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1324081/cannot-connect-to-wi-fi-with-enhanced-open-owe-and-protected-managment-frames) which are required for my application. One suggestion is to try configuring Wi-Fi with wpa_supplicant.

In the default Ubuntu 20.10 installation, wpa_supplicant seems to be not present or disabled:

- /var/log/wpa_supplicant.log does not exist
- $ wpa_cli    returns with    “could not connect to wpa_supplicant”
- /etc/network/interfaces does not exist

However, wpa_supplicant is present:

```
$ which wpa_supplicant
/usr/sbin/wpa_supplicant
$ wpa_supplicant -version
wpa_supplicant v2.9
Copyright (c) 2003-2019, Jouni Malinen <j@w1.fi> and contributors
```

[This article](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1242256/how-to-configure-wpa-supplicant-in-ubuntu-server-20-04) notes that wpa_supplicant was deprecated with Ubuntu 17, but doesn't provide any guidance on re-activating it.

Is there any documentation on how to cause the Wi-Fi configuration in Ubuntu to be controlled by wpa_supplicant? Can wpa_supplicant run together with netplan and Network Manager, or must the others be disabled? If they must be disabled, where is that configuration described?

Edit:
Network Manager has Enhanced Open and WPA3 options available from connection settings for networks that are not in the 6 GHz band.

[image]

However, the 6 GHz network six-e-test-1 does not have the "gear" for accessing settings.

[image: Visible Networks - settings "gear" missing for six-e-test-1]

Comment: In my 20.10 install, both seem to be supported by NM: https://i.postimg.cc/9fStXyrY/Screenshot-from-2021-05-06-16-24-59.png

Comment: @chili555,  See edits in main post. I have the same options for SSIDs that are not in the 6 GHz band. For 6 GHz, the settings are unavailable.

Comment: I wonder if this is actually a firmware and driver issue. Does this command show that 6 gHz frequencies are supported? `iwlist freq` If so, is *six-e-test-1* broadcasting on an available frequency?

Comment: Well, it's been a while, anyway, I wish [https://medium.com/@barry_wu.me/how-to-connect-wi-fi-6e-ap-over-the-6-ghz-band-with-ubuntu-21-04-2a0b4f071ac2](https://medium.com/@barry_wu.me/how-to-connect-wi-fi-6e-ap-over-the-6-ghz-band-with-ubuntu-21-04-2a0b4f071ac2) could be helpful for you.